# How to access numeric property of an object

Tags: php

I have this object:

```
 stdClass Object ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
         [type] => A 
         [quantity] => 30 
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
         [type] => P 
         [quantity] => 129
    ) 
 )
```

However, I cannot access the sub-objects (e.g., `$Data->0->quantity`) because numeric properties of objects are not accessible in PHP.

How can I access the sub-objects without resorting to looping?

Answer (score 1):

Just as any object with public variables:

```
$oStdClass->0->quantity = 10;
```

Or loop trough them.

```
foreach($oStdClasses as $oStdClass) {
     $oStdClass->quantity = 10;
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't work. that's the problem already. I tried your code like this: `echo $this->Data->0->type;` and it gave syntax error.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you got integer members in there, but the foreach loop should work nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit of a strange corner case -- objects generally are not supposed to have properties which aren't valid PHP variable names -- but it should still be possible to get to all of the variables there.

Use get_object_vars.

```
// The following code doubles all of the "quantity" properties of 
// all of the sub-objects.
foreach( get_object_vars( $strangObject ) as $key => $value )
{
     // in here, $key will be your (numeric) property name of the outer object
     // and $value will be the object stored at that property.

     $value->quantity *= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [for-each](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop for that. (If I understand your question right...)

Answer (score 0):

Object's methods and/or properties are accessed via the arrow `->` operator. So to access quantity, you'd do:

```
$quantity = $object->quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe?

```
foreach($class as $v) echo($v->quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting piece. Use variables to address:

```
print_r($item->0);
```

But this works:

```
$index = 0;
print_r($item->$index);
```